# Memory Error when using combination and intersection in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am coding for large graph sampling and meet some memory problems.

```
possible_edges = set(itertools.combinations(list(sampled_nodes), 2))
sampled_graph = list(possible_edges.intersection(ori_edges))
```

The code is supposed to find all combinations of nodes in sampled_nodes, which provided all possible edges formed by these nodes. Then take the intersection with original_edges to find which edge exactly exists.

The problem is when the graph is enormous, the itertools.combinations function would cause memory error.

I've thought to write for loop to iteratively calculate the intersection but takes too much time.

Any help from you guys would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution, instead of take intersection of 2 lists, I choose not to create all combinations for possible_edges.

I pick edges in ori_edges to see if both of the node exists in sampled_nodes.

```
sampled_graph = list(set([(e[0], e[1]) for e in ori_edges if int(e[0]) in result_nodes and int(e[1]) in result_nodes]))
```

This code won't create the huge list and the speed is acceptable.